# Android event tracking with Google Tag Manager

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'd like to add tracking for my android app for event such save/open...
code like this:

```
layoutShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                //handle click
                //TODO: 
                DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(this).getDataLayer();
                dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event","clickButton","lable","save")
                }
            });
```

but I got error:The method getInstance(Context) in the type TagManager is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})

How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `TagManager.getInstance(this)`

use 
`TagManager.getInstance(MyActivity.this)` if you are in an activity,

or `TagManager.getInstance(getActivity())` if you are in a Fragment.

because "this" here represent the listener you are in.

Comment: your info make me clear on the usage,thanks.
For my use case, there is Activity instance as member, so reference the member works.